Convergence Issue using GPAW for Anatase and Rutile
I am quite new to simulation and trying to calculate band structures for Anatase and Rutile. To do so I start with convergence tests in order to find appropriate cutoff energies and k-point meshes. However, my calculations result in almost the same convergence for Anatase and Rutile when plotting energy/atom. Is this possible or am I making a mistake?
Thanks!

In terms of cutoff energy, this is not surprising; consider that this is the number of basis functions you need to accurately describe your wavefunction/density. Increasing cutoff increases your ability to resolve finer features. In both systems, the coarse structure is fairly different, but in terms of the details you have Ti-O bonds of roughly the same length making up your system: they might not be the same, but in terms of the fine features they ought to be very similar, and accordingly show a similar cutoff.
For you k-point mesh, I would be slightly more surprised if they were the same in terms of number of points (they have different shape cells), but if you are thinking about the density of points along a direction, I would expect that to be roughly the same too for the same reason above.
Short answer: these are two very similar systems, so ought to have a similar cut-off energy and k-point density with all other parameters being the same.
Hope that helps,
Rob
